# Why is my laptop's webcam light flashing on and off, sporadically?

Tags: laptop, camera

My laptop's webcam light keeps flashing on and off rarely though, but sporadically? I'm on a DELL, Windows 10. How can I stop the flashing?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the apps that you are running.

One or more of them is accessing the camera.

Skype could do this - I keep Skype closed.

Zoom could do this - I keep Zoom closed.

Microsoft Teams could do this - make sure it is not running.

SnagIt uses the camera on startup, but then not after that at any time.

So these are the apps that use the camera. Look through your apps and close / exit apps such as above.